# Can't read Excel cell value in Visual C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, cell

I read [How to read single Excel cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993735/how-to-read-single-excel-cell-value) and tried it myself. But when I gets to

```
string s = (myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[3, "E"] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
```

Everything was terminated and the form was shown.

```
//Everything worked fine here.
string s = (myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[3, "E"] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
//Everything after this was all skipped!
```

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `string s = myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[3, "E"].Value2`?

Comment: I did tried to put the Value2 as a `var` first and cast it to string. But once the program hit it (before casting to string), the whole thing stopped and the form is shown!!!

Comment: `Value2` as a `var`? I am missing something. Can you simply try `string s = myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[3, "E"].Value2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with reading excel cell is that if there is nothing in it, the cell object is `Null`. Thus, it does not have `.Value2` neither `.Value`.

To find a way how to avoid the check for `Null`, you may use `Convert.ToString()` which evaluates the `Null` to an empty string and thus does not return an error:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    string a = Convert.ToString(wk.Cells[i, 1].Value2);
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Comment: If you run your code with `Convert.ToString()` on an empty cell you'll get `null`. You still need to check for `null` before printing "a".

Comment: @CodeCatia - did you try it, because I am pretty sure I have tried it some 3 years ago and it was working the way I described it.

Comment: Don't know what to say, I checked again and you are right, it works as you described. Also tried `string a = wk.Cells[1, 1].Value2;` and it prints empty string on empty cell...

Comment: @CodeCatia - np, admitting publicly in StackOverflow that you were wrong is some kind of an achievement, probably one of the less common here :)

Answer (score 0):

When the cell has a value, you need the `ToString()`.

And when the cell **doesn't** has a value, then you **don't** need the `ToString()`!

Otherwise the whole program will **skip out** and everything after that was **NEVER** executed!!!

So I guess it's just a problem of if the system was trying to cast a **null** value into a string or not!!!

Comment: Yup, this is true. To make it non-redundant and thus avoid the check for `IsNull` see my updated answer.