# how to edit a calculation cell and read the result cell in an excel file using c#?

Tags: c#, android, ios, excel

The excel file has super long formulas and rather than convert them to C# I would prefer to just be able to read from it the result cell after I input values in the calculations cell via the app which would be written in C#

Answer (score 0):

To partially answer your question, If you're not familiar with using the Interop library within C# I suggest you check out this link for basic implementation.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm

Then, once you've got your app set up to manipulate excel files check out this one for how to read a value from a cell:
[How to read single Excel cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993735/how-to-read-single-excel-cell-value)

HOWEVER, depending on how large your excel file may end up being, it may be a good idea to just go ahead and convert the formulae into C#. Taking a little bit of extra time on that will save you tons of time while waiting for excel to execute statements, as I believe it runs off of/in conjunction with VBA(which is an interpreted language as opposed to C# being a compiled language)