# How to read from Excel and replace certain values in a .txt file

Tags: c#, excel

I am new in c#. I have just some basic knowledge like copy and paste. That means I am not good in c#. And sorry for my english. Now to my problem. I have a notepad.txt file. It contains some parameters with values which I get from an other program.

Description of this .txt File:
**[Unit optional] name_of_parameter = value**

**notepad.txt:**

```
[mm]p0=45
[mm]param1=36.42199010819
[mm]param2=56
param9=56
[degrees]p3=453
[degrees]p4=134
[mm]p5=56
p6=1
p7=1
```

There is no chance to get another style of this output (.txt File).

In addition to this I have an excel sheet with random rows and columns. In the first row are the  **name_of_parameter** like -> param1, p0.....

So I want to replace for example the value of param2 (in my .txt file) with the value of param2 from my excel sheet. I want to do this with all name_of_parameters which exists in both files in a loop because my excel sheet has more than one row. Conclusion i want to manipulate the notepad.txt file.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ9QD.png)

my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Z003DUKJ\Desktop\notepad.txt");
            int stop = 1;



        }
    }
}
```

If somebody has some tipps advices for me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

see the link.

[How to read single Excel cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993735/how-to-read-single-excel-cell-value)

Note that your code had pointed to correct worksheet. You will get access to each cell from the code. You can manipulate the value

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think is:

1. Read all lines, like you did in your code
2. Parse the lines thatcontains `paramNum` to objcets and put these to a `Dictionary<string, double>`.
3. Iterate through your Keys in Dictionary
   and search* for that cell in your excel table associated to your
   Key.
4. If you found the cell that contains the paramter, read it's value
   regarding it's location eg.: if the param in 
   `xlWorkSheet.Cells[row,"A"]` then in your excel file the value is in
   `xlWorkSheet.Cells[row-1, "A"]`.
5. Then replace cell value with your dictionary item's value

How to Read xls file:

```
var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
var xlWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
var ws = (_Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
```

Search for cell:

```
Excel.Range currentFind = null; 
Excel.Range firstFind = null; 

Excel.Range rangeOfParams = Application.get_Range("A1", "E5");
// You should specify all these parameters every time you call this method,
// since they can be overridden in the user interface. 
currentFind = rangeOfParams .Find("param1", missing,
    Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, 
    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
    missing, missing); 

while(currentFind != null) 
{ 
    // Keep track of the first range you find. 
    if (firstFind == null)
    {
        firstFind = currentFind; 
    }

    // If you didn't move to a new range, you are done.
    else if (currentFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
          == firstFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
    {
        break;
    }

    currentFind.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    currentFind.Font.Bold = true; 

    currentFind = rangeOfParams.FindNext(currentFind); 
}
```

Replace value of cell:

```
ws.Cells[2, "A"] = SomeValue;
ws.Cells[2, "E"] = OtherValue;
```

[MSDN Microsoft Excel Solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-search-for-text-in-worksheet-ranges?view=vs-2017)

Comment: thank you so much!!! i will check the code if understand it. maybe i have a question

Comment: Let me know if you have question. This is not the full code, but a path where you can start.

Comment: @kovirli can you send me a full code? I mean a working code? I combine this parts with my code so I have some errors like ".. namespace "_Application could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly?

Comment: Updated my code, sorre for that, I wrongly pasted that _Application and other names.

Answer (score 0):

Following the version excel you have, this nuget package does the job for you

see [link](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)

you have some interesting samples