# c# Excel Interop write string to a cell

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm trying to write a string with C# in an Excel cell. The outcome of that endeavor is not really what i want ;)

The code i use

```
string zelle = String.Format("{0} - {1}",listSheet.Cells[4,1],listSheet.Cells[4, 2]);     
optiSheet.Cells[2, 2] = zelle;
```

The outcome
System.__ComObject-System.__ComObject

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Try reading the cells as `.Cells[...].Value.ToString()`

Comment: Thanks for your help but that not working either.

Now im getting 
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: "'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'Value'"

as an Error

Comment: How about this way (cast to range, then string) https://stackoverflow.com/a/18993776/246342