# Trying to Read an Excel Spreadsheet from a C# applicaton

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

So, here is what I wrote so far.  Getting an error on the (String)cells[] values.  Not sure why I'm getting  Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.String'.

FYI, final code I need the string values of the cells, this is a test prototype

*NOTE REVISED: See String.Format and (Excel.Range) cast, also added Close() and Quit() commands so the workbooks don't remain in use:*

```
namespace ExcelReadTestProject {
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    class ExcelReadTest {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            if ( args.Length==0 ) {
                Console.WriteLine("ExcelReadTest [fullpath_to_excel_file]\n\nExcelReadTest \"C:\Users\User\Documents\ExcelReadTest.xlsx\"");
            } else if ( !System.IO.File.Exists(args[0]) ) {  // file specified not found
                Console.WriteLine("File \"{0}\" not found");
            } else if ( args[0].IndexOf('\\')<0 ) {  // full path not specified
                Console.WriteLine("Need to specify full path to file \"{0}\"");
            } else {
                Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
                app.Visible = false;  // run hidden or minimized
                Excel.Workbook wkbook = app.Workbooks.Open(args[0]);
                Excel.Worksheet wksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wkbook.Sheets[1];
                Excel.Range cells = wksheet.UsedRange;
                int row = 1;
                QRecords recs = new QRecords();
                while ( cells.Cells[row,1]!=null ) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",String.Format("{0}",(Excel.Range)cells.Cells[row,1].Value),String.Format("{0}",(Excel.Range)cells.Cells[row,2].Value),String.Format("{0}",(Excel.Range)cells.Cells[row,3].Value));
                    row++;
                }
                wkbook.Close(0);  // need to close workbook
                app.Quit();  // need to quit EXCEL process
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Initially, I was getting Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll error, resource not found.  Fixed that by copying office.dll from the same directory to the runtime .exe directory too.  With both there, at least it opens the file, but has trouble accessing the cell values.

Comment: What do you mean by `has trouble accessing the cell values`. Please add any error messages.

Comment: You probably want to do something like Cells[foo,bar].Value?.ToString() ... hard casting with (String) is almost never the way in c#. In this case, you're holding a ComObject, not a value. Check with the Quick Debugger and you will see where your data is and how to de-reference it.

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like cells.Cells[row,1] is a `System.__ComObject`, but you are trying to cast it to string by using `(String)cells.Cells[row,1]`.   JP Alioto's comment about `Cells[foo,bar].Value?.ToString()` seems right.  [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18993735/641833) might also be helpful.

Comment: FYI tried a few things, I wanted to use the built in Office features, not download a third party file or library.  Revised the code which works.  Note error was due to the cell[] reference needed to be cast as (Excel.Range) and from there, the .Value property results in an object that can be cast, as long as the type is supported.

Comment: so @PeterSmith, the error I was getting was Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.String'.  The line which the error occurs is the (String)cells.Cells[row,1] reference, cannot convert the COM to String.  Ended up having to cast as Excel.Range, then access the property .Value, also the .Value can sometimes be numeric aka double which cannot be cast to (String), so I used String.Format() to convert whatever it is to String.

Answer (score 0):

If I may, I would like to recommend the library [ExcelDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) for your purposes.

1. It is very easy to use
2. It does not depend on any office products being installed
3. It allows access to spreadsheets using well known types (DataSet / DataTable)
4. It is published under MIT license

The [project page](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) provides detailed information on how to use the library.

This example from the project page shows two ways of reading an excel file:

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        // Choose one of either 1 or 2:
        // 1. Use the reader methods
        do // iterate spreadsheets in the file
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // reader.GetDouble(0);
            }
        } while (reader.NextResult());

        // 2. Use the AsDataSet extension method
        var result = reader.AsDataSet();

        // The result of each spreadsheet is in result.Tables
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I prefer to use built in features rather than downloading a third party library.  I ended up getting it to work, and revised the code.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm glad to hear that you could solve the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

FYI three things

- Added .Close(0) and .Quit() commands to close the workbook and quit the EXCEL.EXE process, which kept running in the background in the previous revision, since I didn't execute these commands
- cells.Cell[row,1] apparently is Excel.Range type and needs to be cast as such to access the .Value member
- The .Value member can be either String or double, and double cannot be cast as (String) so I decided to String.Format("{0}",(Excel.Range)cells.Cells[row,#].Value) to convert the string or double to (String)

Also, FYI when compiling with the built in .NET Framework compiler, syntax is:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /R:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll SPAddVOIPInventory.cs

Lastly, in order for it to run, the office.dll and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll have to be in the same folder as the runtime .exe, I copied them from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\DCF\

Make sure you copy Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to the .cs source folder if you use the compiler syntax shown above.